# What does "check-in" mean for luggage?

Tags: meaning

What does "check-in" mean for luggage?

Does "check-in luggage" mean the opposite to "carry-on luggage"?

Comment: I am curious where you saw this. In the US I have only heard *checked* luggage vs. *carry-on* luggage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you "check" or "check-in" luggage, you turn it in at the ticket counter and it will be transported in the cargo hold and you pick it up at the baggage claim at the end of your flight.

On the other hand, if you "carry on" luggage, you bring it on the plane with you.

Comment: +1 Note, too, that when you *check in* your luggage you receive a *claim check* in return: a numbered ticket that shows the luggage is yours and allows you to *claim* it (assert your ownership), or to put in a *claim* for it if it doesn't show up.

Comment: Good point -- similar to "checking" your hat or coat or umbrella or camera at a venue like the theatre or opera.